# Help Center design suggestions

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, help-center

Links displayed on the right side of the Help Center page seem to be deserted and just hanging in the middle. On child meta sites, these links are enclosed in a colored box which provides some emphasis on the links. Should the same be done for the Help Center page on Meta Stack Exchange? Also, MSE page contains some extra padding on the left disturbing the alignment.

**MSE Help Center page:**

> [image]

**MSO Help Center page:**

> [image]

Culprit seems to be the `.newuser` CSS class on MSE which is missing `backgroud-color` and `border-radius`.

```
.newuser{background-color:#f6f5ee;color:#525252;border-radius:5px;padding-top:8px}
```

Comment: I've retagged this as a bug because I'm pretty sure the misalignment isn't intentional. :) (The categories on the right not being in a box might be, but again, their current alignment is probably a mistake.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alignment bug has been fixed after the recent redesign.

> [image]